# обновление контента в блоке jquery

Tags: jquery

1)Есть скрипт который должен загружать в конкретный блок содержимое других страниц(*about.html, contact.html и т д*) , **url** меняется, в **response** приходит ответ, а вот содержимое блока на стартовой странице(*index.html*) не меняется.
2) если перейти по **url** через адресную строку например(*site.com/about.html*), то на чистой странице выводится содержимое страницы about.html, которое должно отображаться в блоке стартовой страницы(*index.html*) с этим же (*site.com/about.html*)

> **index.html**

```
<div class="container">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="index.html" class="historyAPI">Главная</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html" class="historyAPI">О нас</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html" class="historyAPI">Контакты</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div>
                <div class="jumbotron" id="contentHolder">
                    <h1>Главная!</h1>
                    <p>Здесь какой-то текст главной страницы.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

> script.js

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('.historyAPI').on('click', function(e){      
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        getContent(href, true);
    });
});

window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    getContent(location.pathname, false);
});

// Функция загрузки контента
function getContent(url, addEntry) {
    $.get(url).done(function(data) {
        $('#contentHolder').html($(data).find("#contentHolder").html());
        if(addEntry == true) {
            // Добавляем запись в историю, используя pushState
            history.pushState(null, null, url); 
        }
    });
}
```

> about.html

```
  <div class="jumbotron" id="contentHolder">
                    <h1>О нас </h1>
                    <p>описание блока о нас</p>
                </div>
```

Comment: если по простому, всё у вас правильно, только нужно просто сделать все файлы `about.html` , `default.html`, `contact.html`  по образу `index.html`  тогда  файл `script.js` можно не менять...   (в этом случае можно загружать соответствующие блоки если перейти сразу по URL)

Comment: Akubik, да сделал так, но суть в том что при переходе по URL через адресную строку или при нажатии на F5, браузер направляет на страницу которая в URL

Comment: а надо куда? что, я не понял, вы хотите обновлять блок не переходя по ссылке оставаясь на изначальной странице?

Comment: Akubik, в этом и смысл, на данный момент скрипт меняет URL но остается на прежней странице, но если нажать F5 или сразу с адресной строки ввести URL то переходит по ссылкам

Comment: если вы не хотите переходить по ссылкам, тут 2 пути... либо чтобы это это была не ссылка, либо запретить распространение  события, я правильно вас поинимаю?

Comment: Akubik, ссылка должна быть, ибо это разные страницы откуда будет подгружаться информация с БД и прочее, так же лишать пользователя вводить с адресной строки это глупо

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69795/discussion-between-akubik-and-).

Comment: Akubik, уже в чате

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('#contentHolder').html(data);
```

Этого достаточно. сейчас дам код только в UTF-8 сохраняйте HTML

## script.js

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('.historyAPI').on('click', function(e){      
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        getContent(href, true);
    });
});

window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    getContent(location.pathname, false);
});

// Функция загрузки контента
function getContent(url, addEntry) {
    $.get(url).done(function(data) {
//        $('#contentHolder').html($(data).find("#contentHolder").html());
        $('#contentHolder').html(data);
        if(addEntry == true) {
            // Добавляем запись в историю, используя pushState
            history.pushState(null, null, url); 
        }
    });
}
```

Теперь немного модифицируем скрипт, чтобы он менял содержимое блока `#contentHolder` при нажатии на ссылку страницы , но не переходил по cсылке:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.historyAPI').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    getContent(href, true);
  });
});

window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
  getContent(location.pathname, false);
});

// Функция загрузки контента
function getContent(url, addEntry) {
  $('#contentHolder').load(url + ' #contentHolder', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (addEntry == true) {
      // Добавляем запись в историю, используя pushState
      history.pushState(null, null, url);
    }
  });
}
```

## index.html

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<div class="container">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="default.html" class="historyAPI">Главная</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html" class="historyAPI">О нас</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html" class="historyAPI">Контакты</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div>
                <div class="jumbotron" id="contentHolder">
                    <h1>Главная!</h1>
                    <p>Здесь какой-то текст главной страницы.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

## about.html

```
  <div class="jumbotron" id="contentHolder">
    <h1>О нас </h1>
    <p>описание блока о нас</p>
  </div>
```

## default.html

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="contentHolder">
  <h1>Главная!</h1>
   p>Здесь какой-то текст главной страницы.</p>
</div>
```

## contact.html

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="contentHolder">
  <h1>Контакты</h1>
  <p>Здесь Контакты</p>
</div>
```

PS: если необходимо чтобы функционал работал с любой страницы, а не только с `index.html` необходимо сделать все файлы `about.html` , `default.html`, `contact.html` по образу `index.html`.

Comment: так один холдер в другой вкладываться будут, не?

Comment: teran, смысл в том что бы каждой страницы погружаемой, загружался контент в блок стартовой

Comment: не спешите, сейчас всё довыложу

Comment: спасибо, работает, оба примера у вопросе работают

Comment: Отлично, на выбор, хорошего дня всем!!!

Comment: Akubik, а как загружать соответствующие блоки если перейти сразу по URL?

Comment: тогда немного по другому надо... сейчас

Comment: ответил в комментарии к вашему вопросу

Answer (score 1):

вы пытаетесь сделать `$(data).find("#contentHolder")` то есть у среди потомков корневого узла в пришедшем html найти `#contentHolder`.
Но как видно из вашего `about.html` этот конент-холдер сам является корневым узлом, так что среди потомков вы  ничего не найдете.

вам следует делать

```
$("#contentHolder").html($(data).html());
```

Либо если вы не уверены, что `#contentHolder` всегда является корневым узлом, то предварительно проверить это, либо включить корневой узел в поиск.

Comment: что то все по прежнему не грузит в блоки ничего

Comment: @аноним  вы уверены что `data` содержит тот html, который приведен для about ?

Comment: теперь грузит, но индексную не грузит, начальную

Comment: @аноним вам тут в соседнем, удаленном (а зря) ответе, написали что надо сделать `$(data).find("#contentHolder").addBack().html()`

Comment: teran, немного подкорректировал и работает все с примера if($(data).attr("id") == "contentHolder"){
   $("#contentHolder").html( $(data).html() );
}
else $("#contentHolder").html($(data).find("#contentHolder").html());

Comment: teran, а что делать в случае при переходе через URL загружалась стартовая страница с соответствующими блоками?